# How to check if an input is empty to apply a specific class?

Tags: reactjs

I am new on react. I am creating a view "login", I have two fields in the form, `email` and `password`. I need to check when these inputs are empty to apply a specific `icon` class, and if they are not empty apply another `actived` class.

```
<span className={emailIsEmpty ? "icon" : "icon actived"}>
```

This class is simply to change the color of the icons when the user is entering data into the inputs.
[image]

I Create a "useEffect" for each field.

If the element changes, it will check if the input is empty and will return a boolean indicating the current state.

```
// Email Field
useEffect(() => {
  if (email === "") {
    emailIsEmpty = true;
  } else {
    emailIsEmpty = false;
  }
}, [email]);
```

but I am unable to perform this functionality

> Line 33:25:  Assignments to the 'passwordIsEmpty' variable from inside React Hook useEffect will be lost after each render. To preserve the value over time, store it in a useRef Hook and keep the mutable value in the '.current' property. Otherwise, you can move this variable directly inside useEffect

> Line 24:22:  Assignments to the 'emailIsEmpty' variable from inside React Hook useEffect will be lost after each render. To preserve the value over time, store it in a useRef Hook and keep the mutable value in the '.current' property. Otherwise, you can move this variable directly inside useEffect

### LoginView.js

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

const LoginView = function () {

  let emailIsEmpty,
    passwordIsEmpty = null;

  const [formState, setFormState] = useState({
    email: "",
    password: "",
  });

  const { email, password } = formState;

  const handleInputChange = function (e) {
    setFormState({
      ...formState,
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
    });
  };

// Email Field
useEffect(() => {
  if (email === "") {
    emailIsEmpty = true;
  } else {
    emailIsEmpty = false;
  }
}, [email]);

  // Password Field
  useEffect(() => {
    if (password === "") {
      passwordIsEmpty = true;
    } else {
      passwordIsEmpty = false;
    }
  }, [password]);

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="card-login">
        <div className="card-img">
          <img src="//ssl.gstatic.com/accounts/ui/avatar_2x.png" alt="profile-img" className="profile-img-card" />
          <h1>Login</h1>
        </div>
        <form>
          <div className="form-input">
            <span className={emailIsEmpty ? "icon" : "icon actived"}>
              <i class="fas fa-envelope-open-text"></i>
            </span>
            <input name="email" placeholder="Email address" type="email" onChange={handleInputChange} value={email} />
          </div>
          <div>
            <div className="form-input">
              <span className={passwordIsEmpty ? "icon" : "icon actived"}>
                <i class="fas fa-key"></i>
              </span>
              <input name="password" placeholder="Password" type="password" onChange={handleInputChange} value={password} />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div>
            <button className="button response">Login</button>
          </div>

          <div className="forget-password">
            <Link to="/">Forgot password?</Link>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default LoginView;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, you don't need two flags(emailIsEmpty and passwordIsEmpty). Rather, you can use the state itself to add the class conditionally.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

const LoginView = function () {


const [formState, setFormState] = useState({
 email: "",
 password: "",
});



const handleInputChange = function (e) {
setFormState({
  ...formState,
  [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
});
};


return (
<div className="container">
  <div className="card-login">
    <div className="card-img">
      <img src="//ssl.gstatic.com/accounts/ui/avatar_2x.png" alt="profile-img" className="profile-img-card" />
       <h1>Login</h1>
     </div>
    <form>
      <div className="form-input">
        <span className={!formState.email? "icon" : "icon actived"}>
          <i class="fas fa-envelope-open-text"></i>
        </span>
        <input name="email" placeholder="Email address" type="email" onChange={handleInputChange} value={email} />
      </div>
      <div>
        <div className="form-input">
          <span className={!formState.password ? "icon" : "icon actived"}>
            <i class="fas fa-key"></i>
          </span>
          <input name="password" placeholder="Password" type="password" onChange={handleInputChange} value={password} />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button className="button response">Login</button>
      </div>

      <div className="forget-password">
        <Link to="/">Forgot password?</Link>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
);
};

export default LoginView;
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove UseEffect in your code for changing input value its not a better approach it will re render the component every time value change.
this can be possible if you make  you can simply apply check on your formState.email
or formState password.
Now in your onChnageHandler function.

```
 const handleInputChange = function (e) {
    setFormState({
      ...formState,
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
    });
//put your condition here
  if (formState.email=="")
  {
    setEmailisEmpty(true);
  }
  else{
     setEmailisEmpty(false);
  }
  };
 <form>
      <div className="form-input">
        <span className={emailIsEmpty ? "icon" : "icon actived"}>
          <i class="fas fa-envelope-open-text"></i>
        </span>
        <input name="email" placeholder="Email address" type="email" onChange={handleInputChange} value={email} />
      </div>
      <div>
        <div className="form-input">
          <span className={passwordIsEmpty ? "icon" : "icon actived"}>
            <i class="fas fa-key"></i>
          </span>
          <input name="password" placeholder="Password" type="password" onChange={handleInputChange} value={password} />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button className="button response">Login</button>
      </div>

      <div className="forget-password">
        <Link to="/">Forgot password?</Link>
      </div>
    </form>
```

Answer (score -1):

You are updating a variable inside the `useEffect` function which will not work on render. Because react component only render based on `state` or `props` changes.

So You can check the constant variable before the return but not inside `useEffect`.

```
emailIsEmpty = email === "";
passwordIsEmpty = password === "";

return (
....
```

So your component should be look like-

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

const LoginView = function () {

  let emailIsEmpty,
    passwordIsEmpty = null;

  const [formState, setFormState] = useState({
    email: "",
    password: "",
  });

  const { email, password } = formState;

  const handleInputChange = function (e) {
    setFormState({
      ...formState,
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
    });
  };

  emailIsEmpty = email === "";
  passwordIsEmpty = password === "";

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="card-login">
        <div className="card-img">
          <img src="//ssl.gstatic.com/accounts/ui/avatar_2x.png" alt="profile-img" className="profile-img-card" />
          <h1>Login</h1>
        </div>
        <form>
          <div className="form-input">
            <span className={emailIsEmpty ? "icon" : "icon actived"}>
              <i class="fas fa-envelope-open-text"></i>
            </span>
            <input name="email" placeholder="Email address" type="email" onChange={handleInputChange} value={email} />
          </div>
          <div>
            <div className="form-input">
              <span className={passwordIsEmpty ? "icon" : "icon actived"}>
                <i class="fas fa-key"></i>
              </span>
              <input name="password" placeholder="Password" type="password" onChange={handleInputChange} value={password} />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div>
            <button className="button response">Login</button>
          </div>

          <div className="forget-password">
            <Link to="/">Forgot password?</Link>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default LoginView;
```

---

For the multiple classes, you can use a package called [classnames](https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames) for joining multiple classes together.